# Creating multiple lockup tables Vs. creating single lookup table

Tags: database-design

I have multiple tables for storing our company asset, these tables include:-

•   Vehicles

•   Servers

•   PCs

•   Furniture

Now for each asset I want to create a look up table the stores asset models for example when creating new PC , the user will select the model “Dell vostro 350”, etc . 
But what is better; to define four look up tables( such as vechicle_model , Server_models, Pc_models, furniture_model), or to define one lookup table and have a column describing its type (type = PC )

Regards

Comment: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html

Answer (score 6):

Use separate lookup tables, despite the similarity they may appear to have - unless you a) Want to allow someone to store a `Dell vostro 350` as the type of furniture, or b) want to have significantly more complex constraints inside the database to prevent such cross-selections being recorded.

In fact, your proposal for a single lookup table is so well known, it's even acquired an acronym of it's own - OTLT, short for One True Lookup Table. If you care to search for it, it's almost always mentioned in the same breath as "anti-pattern" or "beginner mistakes".

Answer (score 1):

Do these tables share the same columns, **constraints** and physical storage?

- If yes, they should be one table.
- If not, keep them separate.

Please note that the condition stated above is actually harder to fulfil than it might seem at the first glance. For example, tables should be kept separate if:

- Any key should be unique separately for each table, and not for the union of rows from all tables.
- A foreign key exists in one table but not another, or a foreign key *references* one table but not another.
- A CHECK constraint exists in one table but not in another. This includes even simple things such as NOT NULL.
- Column type or *width* is different.
- Triggers are different.
- Permissions are different.
- Table-level locks need to be taken.
- Tables need to be clustered or partitioned differently, or simply stored on different disks or differ in some other physical storage parameter (depending on DBMS).
- Etc...

So, it's likely you'll need to keep the tables separate.

Answer (score 0):

If you just plan to use for a lookup, I would go for the one table solution.

If you where planing to store other information about the assets based on their model, for example whether a vehicle was petrol / diesel, or a PC was a desktop or laptop, then the multi table solution may work much better.

Comment: but one table will affect performance since i have to filter out the asset which have certain type only. for example when ading new Car i have to search for the models that have their type as Vechicle.what do u think?

Comment: it may have an effect, but, I guess that the table will not be huge 1000s of rows rather than millions and an index on asset_type or assert_type,model_name would help